# Jackson ObjectMapper.readValue throws NullPointerException, LRUMap.get(LRUMap.java:68)

Tags: jackson, fasterxml

I write a hive UDF which looks like below:

```
public class DemoUDF extends GenericUDF{
      private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      
      ... initialize() method...

      public Object evaluate(DeferredObject[] deferredObjects) throws HiveException{
           ... ...
           ActionVO vo = mapper.readValue(target_str, ActionVO.class);
           ... ...
      }
}
```

While I add this function into hive,and execute it with some query,there exists the exception below:

> Caused by : java.lang.NullPointerException
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.LRUMap.get(LRUMap.java:68)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromClass(TypeFactory.java:1255)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromAny(TypeFactory.java:1194)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.constructType(TypeFactory.java:608)

while I change the ObjectMapper declaration to below,it works fine!

```
private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

So why? What effect does it make?

Comment: similar finding: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/503, but then again, why declaring ‘static’ even fixes the NPE ? isn’t 1 objectMapper per udf instance even safer?

Answer (score 0):

I think once you make a variable static then its class level thing and only one copy of that will be stored. The JVM allocates static variable during the class loading time. For non-static ones multiple copies will be created as per class instances and hence need more memory.
Static variables are shared by all objects of a class and have a single instance, while non-static variables are unique to each object and have different values for different objects.